# Interface for dynamicly created objects Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

i want to create translator hook which takes language json files by selected language and return piece of this big object depend on arguments.
how can i create an interface for object which i created dynamicly?
i want to see keys of object after point

**json file**

```
    {
  "main": {
    "price": "Price",
    "deepSearch": "Deep search",
    "search": "Search",
    "details": "Details"
  },
  "add": {
    "aboutHome": "About home",
    "removeAdd": "Remove add",
    "numberOf": "the number of"
  },
  "complex": {
    "apartmentInFloor": "apartment in floor",
    "apartment": "apartment",
    "blok": "blok",
    "corpus": "corpus"
  }
}
```

**My translator hook**

```
import anyLang from "./lang/az.json";
type Page = "main" | "header" | "add" | "complex" | "agency" | "login" | "adding" | "propTypes";

export const useTranslator = (
  page?: Page,
  other?: Page[] // other pages you want include to lang object
) => {
  const langState = useSelector((state: IAppState) => state.header.lang)
  const langObj = require(`./lang/${langState}.json`) as typeof anyLang;

  const _getPageLang = (page?: Page) => {
    if (page && page.toLowerCase() === "main") {
      return langObj["main"];
    } else if (page && page.toLowerCase() !== "main" && Object.keys(langObj).includes(page)) {
      return { ...langObj["main"], ...langObj[page as keyof typeof langObj] };
    } else {
      let allLangs = {};
      Object.keys(langObj).map((key: string) => (allLangs = { ...allLangs, ...langObj[key as keyof typeof langObj] }));
      return allLangs;
    }
  };

  const _getCombinedPages = (page?: Page, other?: Page[] | undefined) => {
    let pageLang = _getPageLang(page);
    let notExists: string[] = [];

    if (other && other.length > 0 && page) {
      other.map((pg: Page) => {
        if (
          Object.keys(langObj)
            .map((obj) => {
              return obj.toUpperCase();
            })
            .includes(pg.toUpperCase())
        ) {
          pageLang = { ...pageLang, ...langObj[pg as keyof typeof langObj] };
        } else {
          notExists.push(pg);
        }
        return pageLang;
      });
    }

    if (notExists.length > 0) {
      console.warn(`${window.location.pathname} \n "${notExists}" is not key of ${langState}.json file`);
    }
    return pageLang as any;
  };

  return _getCombinedPages(page, other);
};
```

**And how i use this hook**

```
const lang = useTranslator("add")
lang.aboutHome
```

i need to see keys of returned object when i type **lang.[...]**

Comment: Are you using the --resolveJsonModule flag?

Comment: yes i am using it

Comment: Getting the type from one of the example files is good but you can go further with this.  For example `type LangObj = typeof anyLang`, `type Page = keyof LangObj`.  In order to return the correct type your hook needs to be a generic which depends on the page.  With a single page it's pretty straightforward but your second argument with an array of pages makes it messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that all languages have the same fields.  Getting the type from one of the example files is good but you can go further with this:

```
type LangObj = typeof anyLang;

type Page = keyof LangObj;
```

In order to return the correct type your hook needs to be a generic which depends on the page. With just one page this is straightforward:

```
export const useTranslator = <P extends Page>(
  page: P
): LangObj[P] =>
```

It becomes messy because you are allowing multiple pages and because you have specific handling of edge cases.  You always add the properties of "main" whether or not it's included.  You return all of the properties if no page is provided.

I'm not convinced that all of this logic and `if` branching really makes sense and I wonder if you shouldn't just return all of the properties and forget the `page` completely.

Using a complicated mess of variadic tuple types, `infer`/`extends`, and recursion we can get a return type for multiple pages.

```
type Returned<Pages extends Page[]> = Pages extends [infer P, ...(infer R)] ?
  (P extends Page ? LangObj[P] : {}) & (R extends [Page] ? Returned<R> : {}) : {}

export const useTranslator = <Pages extends Page[]>(
  ...pages: Pages
): Returned<["main", ...Pages]> => {
```

I am now expecting the pages to be passed as zero to many `string` arguments instead of a `string` and an `array` because I think this makes way more sense.

This return type covers one to many pages and the inclusion of "main".  It doesn't yet cover the scenario where `pages` is an empty array and we return everything.  That case sucks and requires me to take a different approach with `Returned`.  Every weird edge case that you add to your code needs to be handled by the Typescript signature, so code like this is awful to type properly.

There are some ways that Typescript can simplify your code.  We don't need to deal with case-sensitivity for matching keys because we have required that all arguments match the keys and this is case-sensitive.  You can remove your `notExists` checking too (as long as you call the hook with type-safe arguments).

This is all you need:

```
const useTranslator = <Pages extends Page[]>(
  ...pages: Pages
): Returned<Pages> & LangObj['main'] => {
  const langState = useSelector((state: IAppState) => state.header.lang)
  const langObj = require(`./lang/${langState}.json`) as LangObj;

  return pages.reduce(
    // add specific properties for each key
    (obj, page) => ({
      ...obj,
      ...langObj[page]
    }),
    // initial value is the properties for main because it is always included
    // we need to assert the type of the complete object when it starts off incomplete
    langObj.main as Returned<Pages> & LangObj['main']
  );
};
```

You will get autocomplete on the correct properties:

```
// includes "main" and "add"
const lang = useTranslator("add")
lang.aboutHome;
lang.details;

// only includes "main" properties when no pages provided
const lang2 = useTranslator();
lang2.details;

// with multiple types -- including main makes no difference
const lang3 = useTranslator("add", "complex", "main");
lang3.apartment;
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mA7ykw)

Comment: Thank you for this mini tutorial for me  !
u saved my life  